# Debug assertion during text file reading

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to read 4 floating variables from a text file and then put them into a function.

```
void Array::readFile()
{
ifstream myfile1("numbers.txt");
if (!myfile1.is_open()) {
    cout << "The file could not be opened";
}
else {
    while (myfile1.good())
    {
        double a, b, c, d;
        myfile1 >> a >> b >> c >> d;
        //addMethod(a, b, c, d));
    }
}
}
```

And example of textfile data:

```
-0.143562 0.187022 0.130935 0.001797
```

The issue im experiencing is that i get a Debug Assertion Failed! error after the line:

```
else {
```

The error: Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHEAD->nBlockUse)

Right now i cant even test the code inside the while loop since it breaks just before that.I am quite new to c++ so not to experienced in these sort of errors. My text file is located in the debug folder with the exe file.

Here are some gists: Array.cpp: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f9a9942bced0096613bf
Array.h: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ce68c4fe949413487697
Source/main: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7545c4598196501a69d8

Answer (score 0):

The destructor for `Array` does this:

```
delete this->sphereArray;
```

But there is nothing in the constructor (or anywhere else) that initialises it.

Furthermore, `Array::sphereArray` is defined like this:

```
sphere *sphereArray[sizeof(sphere)];
```

You cannot `delete` that.  Maybe you want to go through the *elements* of that array and delete them.  But they are all uninitialised too.  Also, I have a very strong suspicion that line doesn't do what you think it does.  It's quite unusual to declare an array of pointers that is the length of the type they point to.